# Selling used ram [DDr3 SODIMM]. Need to erase?

Tags: forensics, memory

Does DDr3 SODIMM memory hold information after being removed?  I would like to sell the memory I just removed from my computer, however I wasn't sure if I had to wipe/erase it first some how.  Please advise.  Thank you.

Comment: Just don't freeze it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most people will tell you that the RAM is erased as soon as you remove it from you pc. That is not a 100% true. The data fades away bit by bit in around a minute. The exact time depends on the ram module. **To answer your question directly: You can just sell it without any worries.**

Just a sidenote: The time the RAM needs to be flushed can be enhenced by cooling the RAM down rapidly using ice spray for example. This is done to extract encryption keys from the RAM for example. Its caled a cold boot attack.